# Pending changes from a finished job

Tags: db2, transaction, jobs, iseries, db2-midrange

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncommitted changes pending for file MYTABLE in library MYLIB.
>
> CPF325E
>
> Cause . . . . . :   Uncommitted changes are pending for file MYTABLE in library MYLIB for commitment definition MYTABLE.
>
> Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try your request again:
>
> -- Complete the commitment control process by doing a commit or rollback for commitment definition MYTABLE.
>
> -- Change the commitment control option and compile the program again.
>
> Technical description . . . . . . . . :   The commitment definition identifier is X'5CC4C6E3C1C3E3C7D9D7'. The job that initiated the change(s) is 954538/QUSER/QZDASOINIT. The logical unit of work identifier is *N. The lock space identifier is *N. The XID is X'5CD5404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040'.

Problem is, 954538/QUSER/QZDASOINIT is not an active job. It doesn't show up under active jobs and running this:

```
 WRKCMTDFN 954538/QUSER/QZDASOINIT
```

Gives this:

> Job 954538/QUSER/QZDASOINIT not found.

...What is happening? How can a job that was finished be connected to pending changes? How can I rollback those changes?

EDIT: Responding to questions in an Answer:

> Where are you seeing the message?

That specific one is when, in System iNavigator, I right-click MYTABLE and select Journaling. The original error that made me find the problem is when C# throws:

> iDB2SQLErrorException: SQL0910 Object MYTABLE in MYLIB type *FILE has a pending change.

Likewise, I get a "changes are pending" error when trying to remove a referential constraint from MYTABLE.

> Do you have *JOBCTL authority? It may be that the job isn't gone, you just don't have authority to see it.

I don't know, nor do I know how to check. If I run:

```
WRKCMTDFN QUSER/QZDASOINIT
```

Then a bunch of jobs show up, but 954538 is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...

Still no idea what caused this or what was happening. But I managed to fix it. After waiting a day, I was able to delete MYFILE.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing the message?  With the job gone, I wouldn't expect to see that message in an active job.  Do you have *JOBCTL authority?  It may be that the job isn't gone, you just don't have authority to see it.